# How to use plot.window? (in R)

Tags: r, graphics

When I run the following code:

```
xlim <- c(-30,30)
ylim <- c(-5,5)
plot.window(xlim , ylim )
plot.new()
points(1,1)
points(0,0)
```

For some reason, all I'm getting is a graphic window where it seems that the `xlim/ylim` are `c(0,1)`.

Did I miss something about how to use the `plot.window` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You want to do `plot.window()` and `plot.new()` in the opposite order:

```
xlim <- c(-30,30)
ylim <- c(-5,5)
plot.new()
plot.window( xlim , ylim )
points(1,1)
points(0,0)
```

Currently, the `new()` is overriding the settings passed in `window()`

Comment: Hi, what about adding in x,y labels and the title? Thank you!